# Paypal Re-Authorising Transaction. REST-API

Tags: php, paypal

My site is about booking an appointment for massage. For every appointment booked user pays online using their paypal account or credit card. Paypal REST-API is used for making payments.
This appointment can be edited by that particular user before appointment date.

Now this is how current implementation works:
If edited appointment cost goes higher than previous appointment cost, Previous transaction is being void from paypal and user has to make new payments.

**e.g.**
**Appointment Cost :** $50 (status: pending)
**Edited Appointment Cost :** $80
Transaction of $50 will be voided from paypal and user will make new transaction of $80.

**What I want is:**
Transaction of $50 will remain as it is and user will pay remaining $30 for same transaction using transaction ID. Re-authorised kind of thing.

I google about it, but couldn't find anything helpful. So I doubt whether It is possible or not. Any idea how it can be done ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you want to submit an authorization (auth), followed later by a capture of the actual amount.  The REST APIs [support this](https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/api/#authorizations), with the right API calls.